# How to fetch Data from another table and show on single table in PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need help, I have 2 tables Client and Product. I want to fetch data from Product Table on basis of Client Table and show it as whole.

```
productTable
productId     productName      productPrice
1             Abc              100
2             Bcd              200
3             Cde              300

clientTable
clientId        productNameId     clientName
4               2                 A
5               3                 B
6               1                 C
```

I want the table to show the record as:

```
Client Name             Product Name
A                       Bcd
B                       Cde
C                       Abc
```

How can I show them using MVC CI.

Model

```
class Client_model extends CI_model
{
    function All()
    {
        return $client = $this->db->get('client')->result_array();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class Client extends CI_Controller
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Client_model');
        
        $invoice = $this->Client_model->All();
        $data = array();
        $data['client'] = $client;
        $this->load->view('admin/ViewClient', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client Controller Code:-**

```
class Client extends CI_Controller
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Client_model');
        
        $data['clientData']  = $this->Client_model->All();
        
        
        $this->load->view('admin/ViewClient', $data);
    }
}
```

**Client_model Model Code:-**

```
class Client_model extends CI_model
{
    function All()
    {
        return $client = $this->db->get('client')->result_array();
    }
}
```

**ViewClient View Page:-**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.NO</th>
        <th>client Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php if(!empty($clientData)) { 
    $count=1;
foreach($clientData as $client){ 
                
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $client['clientName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php 
 $pid =  $client['productNameId'];
$pdata = $this->db->get_where('productTable',array('productId '=>$pid))->row();
echo  $pdata->productName; ?>
    </td>
    
    </tr>
     <?php $count++;
    } } 
    ?>
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: I have another question if you have time do reply. Thanks

Comment: if this solved your problem then please accept my answer.)

Comment: @Umar Jan  Yes Ask Please?

Comment: You got it ... I have another question will upload in a min.

Comment: No I will upload it so that you can get the credit.

Comment: @Umar Jan please ask another question , if i know then i will try.

Comment: I want to show last Insert ID on page where I want to add another record so that I can add +1 to it and make a record unique.

In MVC CI please.
Do I need to do changes in Model and Controller ?

Comment: where you  want to show last Insert ID in ViewClient View Page?

Comment: Exactly also in AddClient too.

Comment: which `table last Insert ID` you want to show in  `ViewClient` &  `AddClient`?

Comment: My requirements is that when I am inserting new client details I have made a field in it called client unique id in which I give a unique ID to every client on basis of year.  Example I added entry its last ID is 12 now when I am adding new record It shows me client_last_id + 1.